# PHP increase seconds value, roll-around 60

Tags: php, date, format, int

How to increase seconds in a variable ?

to increase in a date .. :

```
date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + 30);
```

but i want to do this :

```
$seconds = 59;
$increase = 3;
$result = $seconds + $increase; // 62
```

i want it to stop by second 60 and re-calculate, the result should become 2 and not 60

Comment: Use a modulus (remainder after integer division). `$result = ($seconds + $increase) % 60;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the modulus operator:

```
$seconds = 59;
$increase = 3;
$result = ($seconds + $increase) % 60; // 2
```